# discord bot (python) "wait_for" "reaction_add" duplicating embed

Tags: python, discord, bots

I've been having an issue with my attempt to make a embed that reveals a list of characters that a play owns. I basically want to have the :left_arrow: and :right_arrow: emojis as reaction to pan left and right between the long database of characters a user owns.

I did in fact manage to do that however I noticed that if I use the command which shows an embed with all the characters twice before the timeout of one and then i click the left arrow to see the next page it goes to the next page on both embeds instead of just the one i reacted to.

Here's my source code.

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["collection", "c"])
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def characters(self, ctx):
    if not await bot.check_channel_permissions(ctx.author, ctx.channel): # Checks if the bot can send messages in the channel.
        return

    playerData = await bot.get_player_data(ctx.author, ctx.channel) # Returns the user's data.

    if playerData:

        if len(playerData["Characters"]) > 0: # Checks amount of characters the user owns.

            if len(playerData["Characters"]) > 20: # Player owns 20 so it will create an embed with reactions.

                global pageNumber
                global maxPages
                pageNumber = 1
                maxPages = math.ceil(len(playerData["Characters"]) / 20)

                embed = await characters.setupEmbed(self, playerData, ctx.author, pageNumber)

                currentEmbed = await ctx.channel.send(ctx.author.mention, embed=embed)

                await currentEmbed.add_reaction("⬅")
                await currentEmbed.add_reaction("➡")

                async def listenForRection(self, mainUser): # Waits until the user reacts with the left or right arrow in order to edit the current embed.

                    global pageNumber # the current page (20 characters are shown a page)
                    global maxPages # the max amount of pages the user can pan between.

                    def check(reaction, reactionuser):
                        if reactionuser != mainUser:
                            return False
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '⬅' and pageNumber > 1:
                            return True
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '➡' and pageNumber < maxPages:
                            return True
                        else:
                            return False

                    try:
                        reaction, reactionuser = await self.client.wait_for(
                            "reaction_add",
                            timeout=60,
                            check=check
                        )
                    except:
                        asyncio.TimeoutError
                        await currentEmbed.edit(content="Timed out.")
                    else:
                        if str(reaction.emoji) == '⬅':
                            pageNumber += -1
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "➡":
                            pageNumber += 1
                        newEmbed = await characters.setupEmbed(self, playerData, mainUser, pageNumber) # Returns an embeded list given the page number and info on the user.
                        await currentEmbed.edit(embed=newEmbed) # re-edits the current embed to show the next or previous page.
                        await listenForRection(self, mainUser) # re-runs the function again to listen for the next reaction.

                await listenForRection(self, ctx.author) # runs the listener once so that it can begin detecting and re-running on its own.


            else: # player will get an embeded list with no reactions since they only have 1 page of characters.
                embed = await characters.setupEmbed(self, playerData, ctx.author, 1)
                await ctx.channel.send(ctx.author.mention, embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.reply("You don't have any characters.")
```

What would happen is I run the command once and it works perfectly fine. Then when I run it again before the timeout and click a reaction it either wouldn't work or run both on the new embed and the old. I spent a ton of hours trying multiple things and searching but I didn't manage to do much apart from creating a new bug right after i fix the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually an ext library for making paginated menus called [discord-ext-menus](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus). It does most of the work for you so you don't have to create your own.

Comment: how would i go about implementing it, such as detecting reactions, formatting each page and such. i'm still pretty new when it comes to bot development on discord so i didn't really understand anything on it other than the simple MyMenu class example.

Comment: It does that for you, you have to use the `MenuPages` class to do it. the `MenuPages` will automatically add the reactions and control the switching of pages. All you have to do is subclass `ListPageSource`, which will hold the actual data in the embed. Then pass the source into `MenuPages` along with your data. There's an example [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus#pagination).

Comment: ah I get it now, btw I noticed that if I click a reaction and then click to unreact it will still shift pages. is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: No, unfortunately that's how it was made, the reaction event will trigger the page switching. You could always source dive and try to remove some stuff, but that is not recommended. There is another option that is also not recommended, which is to create your own `MenuPages` that immediately removes the reaction after someone adds it so that you would only have one reaction at a time. However this is frowned upon because its an unnecessary API call and the owner of the library doesn't like it.  If you do want to do it though just tell me.